# How to include xml in a component's view?

Tags: xml, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

### Description:

I was going through the documentation and some of the projects on NativeScript's github like [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-drawer-navigation-ng), which talks about how to implement a [Drawer Navigation](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started).

I was curious to notice that the Drawer Component's XML was copied and placed on the top of every page's view.

For example in the **home.component.html**

```
<!--
RadSideDrawer is a UI component part of the Progress NativeScript UI set of components.
Learn more about the RadSideDrawer UI component and how it can be customized in this documentation article:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started
The RadSideDrawer component is designed to be used as a root element and
it shouldn't have any other siblings other than the <ActionBar> component.
-->
<RadSideDrawer #drawer showOverNavigation="true" [drawerTransition]="sideDrawerTransition">
    <!--
    Use the tkDrawerContent directive to display the content of the app drawer on this page.
    -->
    <StackLayout tkDrawerContent>
        <MyDrawer [selectedPage]="'Home'"></MyDrawer>
    </StackLayout>

    <!--
    Use the tkMainContent directive to display the content of the page when you have an app drawer.
    -->
    <StackLayout class="page appPage homePage" tkMainContent>
    </StackLayout>
</RadSideDrawer>
```

This piece of code will be copied and placed on the top of every other page view. That's a lot of redundant code.

### Question:

Why did they copy around the drawer view in every page? And is there a way to include a view?

*The angular way would simply to write the drawer's selector in the html file, however this does not work since NativeScript view's are XML.*

Answer (score 0):

If youre using angular that should work. Create a component for your drawer content, then just set the selector and add it in your Drawer view.

like

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-drawer-content",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./drawercontent.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./drawercontent.component.css"],
})
```

Add it to your app.module.ts file in declarations, then just use `<my-drawer-content></my-drawer-content>` in your main view.

Comment: Except it doesn't though, which is what I had pointed out when I spoke about adding the selector. I'll run it again tomorrow, see if I didn't forget anything and add the error I'm getting to my post. Thanks.